# Oneliner to archive, test the archive and remove source folder or stop if error

Tags: shell-script, shell, tar

I've made my small shell function to un-compress the latest archive in a specific folder, then use it (code removed for sake of clarity), and then make an archive, test it and if everything is ok, remove the `tmp` folder, *otherwise* **just stop**. And sometimes, it doesn't work (archive problem I dont know when I retry it works), so I should **not** remove the folder, and stop. My small script doesn't work. I've made a comment where the one-liner doesn't work, so here's my script:

```
mine() {
    src="/mnt/myfolder"
    game_folder="MyGameFolder"
    src_folder="${src}/${game_folder}"
    src_archive="${src}/${game_folder}.tar"
    tmp="/tmp/tmpfolder"

    # Expand path (don't do this if path is set by user input!):
    echo "Folder tmp: '${tmp}'."
    [ ! -d "${src}" ] && echo "Folder src: '${src}' not found. Exiting." && return 1
    rm -rf "${tmp}"
    mkdir "${tmp}"
    [ ! -d "${tmp}" ] && echo "Folder tmp: '${tmp}' not found. Exiting." && return 1
    cd "${tmp}"
    if [ -d "${src_folder}" ]; then
        # Archive folder exists -> find latest archive and uncompress:
        latest="$(ls -t "${src_folder}/" | head -1)"
        full_latest="${src_folder}/$latest"
        if [ -f "${full_latest}" ]; then
            echo Copying "${latest}"...
            cp "${full_latest}" .
            echo Unpacking "${latest}"...
            tar xf "${latest}"
        else
            echo "Warn: no archive found in: '${src_folder}'"
        fi
    else
        echo "No folder: '${src_folder}', creating folder, it's a new game..."
        mkdir "${src_folder}" \
        || (echo "Unable to create '${src_folder}'" ; return 1)
    fi

    archive="$(date '+%Y.%m.%d-%Hh%Mm%Ss').${game_folder}.tar.bz2"
    printf "\n\nMaking archive '${archive}'..."

    # here's the one-liner that doesn't work:
    tar cjf "${archive}" "${game_folder}/" &&
    mv "${archive}" "${src_folder}/" &&
    latest="$(ls -t "${src_folder}/" | head -1)"
    && tar -tf "${latest}" ||
    (echo "Error tar cjf ${archive}" "${src_archive}/" && exit 1)
    rm -rf "${tmp}"
    cd
    printf "\nDone. You can exit the shell if you want now.\n\n"
    return 0
}
```

What should I change to make it work?

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: I've edited your code to remove unnecessary escaped newlines, which hopefully will make your syntax error more conspicuous.